# Javascript: adding 'false' after running a function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm analyzing a plugin as I want to modify it. 
I see various events firing functions like this:

```
    document.getElementById(this.config.form).addEventListener("submit", this._submit, false);
```

My question is - what does `false` on the end actually do? Is it the same as adding `return = false` on the end of a function? If so, what is the purpose of adding this?

Comment: Sometimes simply looking up the function in google will give you an answer

Comment: I actually tried but could not find what I was after. If I knew to search for `useCapture` it would have been easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [`useCapture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) variable.

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate
>   capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type
>   will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched
>   to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed
>   explanation. If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Answer (score 2):

Taken from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

useCapture Optional
If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.
Note: useCapture became optional only in more recent versions of the major browsers; for example, it was not optional prior to Firefox 6. You should provide this parameter for broadest compatibility.