# What does false do at the end of addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, function

This is pretty basic question and I've found the same question here on Stack Overflow, however I found the answer less than adequate at explaining the answer (which is why I'm asking again).

What does `},false);` do at the end of a function?

For example :

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(){ 

// Do something

},false);
```

Can someone explain what this actually does? Is it just for `addEventListener` functions or can it be used in other functions?

Here is the same question where the answer is simply copy and pasted from MDN: 
[Javascript: adding 'false' after running a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968184/javascript-adding-false-after-running-a-function)

Comment: Well, it depends on the function, don't you think so? It's like asking what does `33` do as second argument.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. It's [another argument to `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) specifying that the event should be caught during the bubbling phase and not during the capture phase.

Here's another way of doing it that might be more obvious to you:

```
function doSomething() {
    // Do something
}

element.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
```